# How do I add an "add Image" button to the right side of my Gallery view?

Tags: android, layout, view, gallery

I have used the Gallery widget to display a set of pictures, but would like to add an image at the end with an OnClickListener that will allow me to add further images to my list.

How can I add something to the right side of a Gallery View?

Will putting the Gallery and a button inside a HorizontalScrollView work?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to provide the user with a way to fetch more data at any point in the gallery, or only when they have reached the end?  Is it reasonable for your use case to do this automatically behind the scenes, for example when they reach the last item in the gallery?

Comment: Putting a horizontal `ScrollView` inside another `ScrollView` is not going to work well. I would look for other solutions.

Comment: Jon O - Yes, that is exactly the behavior I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I see doing this:

In your adapter you should override the method getCount() and set it so that it return the number of images you wish to display + 1.

In your getView/bindView/newView (depending on which adapter you used) you should check to see if the position you are inflating is == getCount() - 1. if so, you should inflate a view that contains your "Add new image" button. Then you just need to attach your onClick listener to that button and handle the insertion of new images

Answer (score 1):

> Will putting the Gallery and a button inside a HorizontalScrollView work? Or is there a better way to do this?

- probably not. There is no way for the views to differentiate which touch events should go to the gallery and which to the HorizontalScrollView.

You need to set your Gallery width to be something less than FILL_PARENT, then you can put the ImageButton to the right of it with `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/galleryId"`

That way both will be on the screen, the "add" button will always be shown and the gallery will be able to scroll to reveal all of the images that are contained in it.

Comment: That's not what I want though.  That would take up unnecessary space for the add button.  I just need to be able to get to it by scrolling, but would like the entire screen to be available for images the rest of the time.